# How to dynamically change import paths in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a set of exports that I normally import from one directory:

```
import { myThing } from 'path/to/dir/es5/things'
```

However, if I run webpack with a specific NODE_ENV set, I would like the root of all such imports to be treated as es6 instead:

```
import { myThing } from 'path/to/dir/es6/things'
```

How can I do this, e.g. have webpack dynamically resolve `path/to/dir/es5/*` to `path/to/dir/es6/*`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an alias for that.

For example, in your webpack configuration, you can use something like:

```
const alias = {};
if (NODE_ENV === ...) {
    alias['path/to/dir/es5'] = 'path/to/dir/es6'
}
```

Further reading: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

Answer (score 1):

Here is my way of handling this stuff.

#### Built-in DefinePlugin coupled with env variable.

in your package.json, add env variable in following way

```
"script": "... webpack --env.SOME_ENV_VAR=value -p"
```

Then, add your DefinePlugin inside your webpack.config file

```
plugins: [
    ...

    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        SOME_ENV_VAR: env.SOME_ENV_VAR,
    }),

    ...
]
```

Then you can use SOME_ENV_VAR as global variable inside your code

```
/* global SOME_ENV_VAR */    

const esX = SOME_ENV_VAR === value ? 'es5' : 'es6';

myThing = require(`path/to/dir/${esX}/things`)
```